# Create a cookie if (and only if) it doesn't already exist

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

**I want to:**

1. Check to see if a cookie with name of "query" exists
2. If yes, then do nothing
3. If no, create a cookie "query" with a value of 1

Note: I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
if($.cookie('query') === null) { 
    $.cookie('query', '1', {expires:7, path:'/'});
}
```

Alternatively, you could write a wrapper function for this:

```
jQuery.lazyCookie = function() {
   if(jQuery.cookie(arguments[0]) !== null) return;
   jQuery.cookie.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Then you'd only need to write this in your client code:

```
$.lazyCookie('query', '1', {expires:7, path:'/'});
```

Comment: i think `!=` should be `==` :p

Comment: Notice that == is not the same as === (or != vs !==).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920055/object-function-a-breturn-new-e-fn-inita-b-h-has-no-method-cookie

Answer (score 6):

this??

```
$.cookie('query', '1'); //sets to 1...
$.cookie('query', null); // delete it...
$.cookie('query'); //gets the value....

if ($.cookie('query') == null){ //Check to see if a cookie with name of "query" exists
  $.cookie('query', '1'); //If not create a cookie "query" with a value of 1.
} // If so nothing.
```

what more do you want??

Comment: @Ozaki - I 'm guessing you misunderstood it... what I'm trying to show are the possible options... well I'm glad you solved it now... :) cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Jacobs answer but I prefer to test for undefined.

```
if($.cookie('query') == undefined){
    $.cookie('query', 1, { expires: 1 });
}
```

Comment: With the latest update from the script, `null` is now deprecated and `undefined` must be used.

Comment: Why do you say that 'null' is now deprecated? I was not able to find any supporting material on this online. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features).