# Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'

Tags: jquery, cookies

trying to get the value of a `cookie` if its set and update a `div` with the `cookie` value, otherwise generate a random number between 80-100, set that as the `cookie`, and then update the `div`.

im getting the error:

```
Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'cookie'
```

heres my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var thecounter = '';

    if ($.cookie('thecounter') == null)
    {
        thecounter = $.randomBetween(80, 100);
        $.cookie('thecounter', thecounter, { path: '/' });
    }
    else
    {
        thecounter = $.cookie('thecounter');
    }

    $('dd-counter-num').html(thecounter);

    setTimeout(newtime, 5000);

});

function newtime () {

    var newtime = $.cookie('thecounter') + $.randomBetween(1, 2);
    $.cookie('thecounter', newtime, { path: '/' }); 
    $('dd-counter-num').html(newtime);
    setTimeout(newtime, 5000);

}
```

Comment: Looks like this was the plugin you were looking for: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie Figured I'd add it since this helped me out as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no `cookie` method in *standard* [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Perhaps the code requires on [jquery-cookie](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) or another plugin?

Happy coding.

Comment: i thought the method was built into jquery from a tutorial i read that didn't include the plugin URL. i found the plugin and it works now. thank you.

Comment: hi scarhand...from where did you got the jquery-cookie plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you are referencing jquery.cookie.js after any standard jquery references.

> *I encountered this error when editing a page using [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). It was first loading jquery, then
>   jquery.cookie.js, then the foundation.min.js file. I didn't realize was the custom
>   foundation.min.js file already had jquery built-in, so executing JQuery again was causing the cookie
>   javascript to fail.*

Answer (score 0):

1) Download this plugin from GitHub: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

2) Put it in your scripts folder.

3) Include it on your website:

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Worked for me.