# Check if cookie exist in general, not a specific cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I detect if the website has set a cookie in general without checking lots of individual cookies.

I looked at this similar question: [Create a cookie if (and only if) it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824021/check-if-cookie-exists-if-not-create-it). But the solutions provided there check if a specific cookie exist, not just cookies in general.

I have tried:

```
if($.cookie) {  
 //code   
}
```

Comment: Wild guess but have you tried `$.cookie().length` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery really isn't necessary to check if the current domain has set a cookie in the user's browser, just use raw JS:

```
if(document.cookie.length > 0) {
    // do stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check if cookie exists:

```
if (document.cookie === "") {
  // do something if no cookie exists
}
```

I would not use jquery for this to safe memory/processing

Comment: document.cookie will always be a string,  and `"" != null`

Comment: wouldn't `!= null` interpret as `if document.cookie is not equal to null` which therefore means if cookie exist. so shouldnt it be `==`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the $.cookie plugin for this:

```
if (document.cookie) {
    // at least one cookie has been set...
}
```