# jQuery blockUI just on first page load

Tags: jquery, popup, blockui, jquery-blockui

I'm using this snippet for blockUI (jQuery plugin) to display a 'blahblah' text for 15 seconds, then it automatically disappears and unlocks the page.

```
 <script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

         jQuery.blockUI({ 
             message: 'Blah blahblah', 
             timeout: 15000 
         }); 
 }); 
 </script>
```

Is there a way to display this just on first page load and not on every page of the site..?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify whether you want to run the blockUI:

1. Only once the first time a user visits the site. If so, check if a cookie is set before running the blockUI code, and then set it after running the code. See [Create a cookie if (and only if) it doesn't already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824021/check-if-cookie-exists-if-not-create-it).
2. Only once every time the user visits a specific page on the site. If so, just set and check a cookie on that page. Otherwise, use a div (e.g. `homediv`) specific to that page and put the code in a load function for that: `$('#homediv').load(function () {  //put the logic above here });`

**Edit**

If it is the first one, and you only want to show the message once a week to visitors to the site, then try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  if($.cookie('firstvisit') == null) { 
     jQuery.blockUI({
         message: 'Blah blahblah',
         timeout: 15000
     });
     $.cookie('firstvisit', '0', {expires:7, path:'/'});
  }
});
```

Change the `7` to the number of days to pass before you want to show the message again.

Comment: I'm looking for the first option. :)
So, would something like this work?
http://pastebin.com/gZqa9ZdK

(first set the cookie to 1 if not present, then run the function if cookie 1 is present)..

Comment: Edited with example: check if someone has visited already. If they have not, run blockUI, then set the cookie so when they visit a page again, it won't run.