# jquery cookies code not working

Tags: jquery, cookies

can't seem to get this code to work, its not throwing errors, but something just isnt right as its not saving the cookie.

Basically on click i need it to check if the cookie is active, if not it needs to add it. This is remove a popup on the website.

```
$('.close-reveal').on(click, function(){
        // if no cookie
        if (!$.cookie('alert')) {
            $('.subscribe-scroller').hide();
            // set the cookie for 24 hours
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
            $.cookie('alert', true, { expires: date });
        }

});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824021/create-a-cookie-if-and-only-if-it-doesnt-already-exist

Comment: Thanks Andrianopolis, jquery is not my strength, so that link you sent makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Is this the lib you're using? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie I haven't tested this, but I suspect your problem is the attempt to set a boolean value to a cookie. If I'm right about that being the lib, read this bit about JSON in the docs: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json

Comment: Ye thats the library, will ready that now, thanks!

Comment: None of this makes sense to me :( how can i apply this to my code above?

Comment: Try adding this line of code, before all the code you showed us here: `$.cookie.json = true;`

Comment: Unless you really need specifically cookies, you should use localstorage instead. It's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You need the quotes around the true.

Try this:

```
$('.close-reveal').on(click, function(){
        // if no cookie
        if (!$.cookie('alert')) {
            $('.subscribe-scroller').hide();

            $.cookie('alert', 'true', { expires: 1 });
        }

});
```

Cookies are only string-valued. If you want to treat the value as a boolean, you need to parse it back to a boolean when the cookie value is read back out.

Secondly why making the effort of calculating one day if you can simply enter 1 for one day?